# Memory leaks in child process after fork() is called in parent, why?

Tags: c, memory-leaks, malloc, fork, valgrind

Mac OS X 10.13.4. Running this program triggers memory leak signals in Valgrind and leaks system call:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>

char    *ft_strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t  cur;

    cur = -1;
    while (s2[++cur] != '\0')
        s1[cur] = s2[cur];
    s1[cur] = '\0';
    return (s1);
}

void    ptr_test()
{
    char    *ptr;

    ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15);
    printf("FIRST: %p\n", ptr);
    ft_strcpy(ptr, "Hello, World!");
    printf("SECOND: %p\n\n", ptr);
    free(ptr);
}

int     main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;

    pid = fork();
    while(1)
        ptr_test();
    if (pid != 0)
        wait(NULL);
    return (0);
}
```

leaks sys call:

```
Process:         main [98746]
Path:            /nfs/2018/p/patrisor/Desktop/ptr/main
Load Address:    0x1095a2000
Identifier:      main
Version:         ???
Code Type:       X86-64
Parent Process:  main [98687]

Date/Time:       2019-09-22 05:28:32.273 -0700
Launch Time:     2019-09-22 05:28:23.881 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.13.4 (17E199)
Report Version:  7
Analysis Tool:   /usr/bin/leaks

Physical footprint:         280K
Physical footprint (peak):  280K
----

leaks Report Version: 3.0
Process 98746: 176 nodes malloced for 27 KB
Process 98746: 4 leaks for 4128 total leaked bytes.

Leak: 0x7f9d9ad00040  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x1095a7000
Leak: 0x7f9d9ad00050  size=16  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x1095a7000
Leak: 0x7f9d9b800800  size=2048  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x1095a7000
Leak: 0x7f9d9b801000  size=2048  zone: DefaultMallocZone_0x1095a7000
```

Valgrind:

```
==1388== LEAK SUMMARY:
==1388==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==1388==    indirectly lost: 4,096 bytes in 2 blocks
==1388==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==1388==    still reachable: 215 bytes in 7 blocks
==1388==         suppressed: 27,726 bytes in 170 blocks
==1388==
==1388== ERROR SUMMARY: 3 errors from 3 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 13)
```

Originally I suspected it was an issue with free() not working with the correct malloced addresses. However, when I manually scanned the memory usage of the process, no significant increase in it's usage occurred during runtime. Later I suspected it was the child process not ending correctly, and maybe creating zombie processes. The leak happens somewhere in the beginning, where free is called. Is there a problem with the function itself, or...? I seem to be very lost.

Any guesses?

Comment: valgrind should be giving you information on where the leaking memory was allocated that would be useful to include. And did you really intend for both processes to enter infinite loops?

Comment: How do you get a "leak summary" from a program that never exits?

Comment: Move ```while (1)``` to ```for (int i = 0; i < 1024; i++)```, and here is no memory leak.

Comment: Seems to me that if an infinite loop is calling a function where memory is allocated, then later freed and you happen to terminate the program (which has to be how this program is exiting), it's expected that this function will be interrupted before it can free the memory it allocated, right? As Tokhta mentions, if the loop is finite, then the function will free its memory and there's no mid-stream interruption to cause a leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the following contains comments on problems with the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>


/* 
 * strongly suggest:
 * #include <string.h> and
 * eliminating this function and in ptr_test()
 * strcpy( ptr, "Hello, World! );
 */
char    *ft_strcpy(char *s1, const char *s2)
{
    size_t  cur;

    /* this causes an implicit conversion to unsigned
     * so the value will be seen as a VERY LARGE number
     * suggest initialize to 0 then use: 
     * while( s2[cur++] != '\0' )
     */
    cur = -1;         
    while (s2[++cur] != '\0')
        s1[cur] = s2[cur];
    s1[cur] = '\0';
    return (s1);
}

void    ptr_test()
{
    char    *ptr;

    /*
     * returned value from malloc has type `void*` 
     * which can be assigned to any pointer
     * casting just clutters the code, 
     * making it more difficult to understand, debug, etc
     * suggest removing that cast.
     */
    /* sizeof( char ) is defined in the c standard as 1
     * multiplying anything by 1 has no effect
     * suggest removing that expresson
     */
    /*
     * when calling any of the heap allocation functions
     * always check (!=NULL) the returned value
     * to assure the operation was successful
     * if not successful, call 'perror( "malloc failed" );
     * to output your error message and the text reason
     * the system thinks the error occurred to 'stderr'
     */
    ptr = (char *)malloc(sizeof(char) * 15); 

    printf("FIRST: %p\n", ptr);

    ft_strcpy(ptr, "Hello, World!");
    printf("SECOND: %p\n\n", ptr);
    free(ptr);
}

int     main(void)
{
    pid_t   pid;

    pid = fork();

    /*
     * this runs 'ptr_test()' FOREVER
     * and in the fork() error condition FOREVER
     * and in the child process  FOREVER
     * and in the parent process FOREVER
     * 
     * note: 'exit()' and EXIT_SUCCESS are from
     *     the header file: `stdlib.h`
     * Suggest:
     * if( !pid )
     * { // then child process
     *     for( int i=0; i<1024; i++ )
     *         ptr_test();
     *     exit( EXIT_SUCCESS );
     */
    while(1)
        ptr_test();

    /* there are three types of returned values from 'fork()'
     * <0  means an error occurred
     * ==0 means in the child process
     * >0  means in the parent process
     * 
     * a test for '!=0' will 'catch' the error AND the parent
     * however, there is no child process for the parent to 'wait()' 
     * strongly suggest testing for each condition separately
     * I.E.
     * if( pid < 0 )
     *     //handle error
     *     perror( "fork failed" );
     * else if( !pid )
     *     // handle child process ...
     *     exit( EXIT_ SUCCESS );
     * else
     *     // handle parent process
     *     wait( NULL );
     */
    if (pid != 0)

        /* the prototype for 'wait()' is missing
         * strongly suggest adding the header files:
         * #include <sys/types.h>
         * #include <sys/wait.h>
         */
        wait(NULL);
    return (0);
}
```